# unable to disable word wrap in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I'm trying to write in a text window with word wrapping disabled & horizontal scrollbar, like this:

```
root = Toplevel()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (350,400))
af=Frame(root)
chtext = Text(af, width=45, wrap=None,font=("Arial",12)) 
chxscrollbar=Scrollbar(chtext, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=chtext.xview)
chtext["xscrollcommand"]=chxscrollbar.set
af.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
chtext.pack(side="left", expand=1, fill="both")
chxscrollbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", expand=False)
```

my problem is that it still wordwraps what I write into it... am I missing something obvious???

thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`None` is not a valid value for the wrap option. You need to use the string `"none"` or the tkinter variable `NONE`. By specifying the python value `None` you are actually requesting the default value, which is `"char"`

```
chtext = Text(af, width=45, wrap="none", font=("Arial",12))
```

Comment: wonderful! That was it... though I find it rather inconsistent with the rest of my python code, where None is used everywhere