# How to force tkinter text widget to stay on one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create an object akin to Label, however I want it to also be selectable for copy-pasting. I have done so using the Text widget:

```
class CopyLabel (Text):
    def __init__ (self, master, text = '', font = None):
        if font is None:
            super().__init__(master = master, height = 1,
                             borderwidth = 0, width = len(text),
                             bg = master['background'])
        else:
            super().__init__(master = master, height = 1,
                             borderwidth = 0, font = font,
                             width = len(text), bg = master['background'])
        self.insert(1.0, text)
        self.configure(state = 'disabled')
```

I end up displaying this widget with a grid. However, I randomly find the last 1 or 2 characters not showing. When investigating this, it seems the Text widget is splitting those characters off to a new line (when selecting the text, it is possible to drag down to see this second line). The biggest problem is the unpredictable nature of this splitting (I tried doing width = len(text) + 2, but I still occasionally get this line splitting behaviour). Is there any way to remedy this behaviour?

EDIT: setting wrap = 'none' fixed the line splitting behaviour, but the text is still getting cutoff. Now I have to scroll horizontally instead of vertically to see the text, but I guess that is a different question from what I posed.

Comment: maybe [wrap="none"](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.config-method) - `tk.Text(root, wrap='none')` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to disable word wrap in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029157/unable-to-disable-word-wrap-in-tkinter)

Comment: @furas. That fixed the line breaking problem, but now it seems to be cutting the labels off (I need to scroll horizontally the text to see it).

Comment: you have to use [Scrollbar](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm) to scroll it. Or use [ttk.scrolledtext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html)

Comment: correction:  ttk.scrolledtext has only vertical scrollbar so you have to use `Scrollbar` with `Text`

Comment: Not really what I'm going for. My end goal is reproducing behaviour of Label that is selectable. The CopyLabel is then used to display a table of data (each piece of information has its own position on a grid).

Comment: If it's one line, why not use an Entry widget? It's specifically designed one single line input.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: Just tried that. But it looks worse (indented into the frame) and it still suffers the same problem of cutting off text.

Comment: You can change the border so it looks flat. It sounds like your problem is simply that you're not making the widget wide enough to accomodate the text. Just make it bigger, and move on.

Comment: Actually, I just realized what was causing the problem. I was changing the font for the text. Since not all fonts are the same width, it has been cutting off some texts. The CopyLabel widget works as intended if the font is unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're experiencing is called *wrapping* and can be disabled modifying Text widget's `wrap` option, as in :

```
self['wrap'] = 'none'
```

or

```
self.config(wrap='none')
```

Comment: That fixed the wrapping, but now my displayed texts are getting cutoff instead. Anyway to fix that without making the Text width larger than it needs to be?

Comment: You could use a scrollbar widget, or write a much more complex method to dynamically resize the widget based on its content. That's a separate question and should be researched based on what behavior you want and if you can't find a solution, then you should ask in SO.